# Java EE findAll() returns duplicate final entry to list after write to database

Tags: jakarta-ee, derby, glassfish-4

I have a small application running on GlassFish. Part of it involves writing some details about a horse to a Derby database. I use an auto-generated session facade and entity class to write to the database. This works correctly, and I can see the data is written correctly using NetBeans SQL editor. If I then use `List allHorses = aHorseFacade.findAll();` to fill a list with all the entries in the table the newest entry is duplicated twice and the previous final entry is gone. If I then re-deploy the application it works as expected and `findAll()` fills the list as it should. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Examine your derby.log (enabling `derby.language.logStatementText` if necessary) to see what **actual** SQL statements your program is issuing to your database, then see if you can understand the behavior you're seeing more precisely.

Comment: Thank-you for the advice. Once I (eventually) managed to enable `derby.language.logStatementText` and examined the logs it seems the application is issuing the correct SQL statements. I am at a loss. The database is written to correctly, but after `SELECT IDNUMBER, NAME, USERNAME FROM APP.HORSES` is executed it does not return what I can see through NetBeans is in the HORSES table. Thanks anyway though, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Heh, I figured it out :) After a little more reading I realised that in `persistence.xml` the Shared Cache Mode was set to 'Unspecified'. Setting it to 'None' resolved the issue. It took me six hours to figure this out... I'd cry if I wasn't so damn pleased. Thanks again for your help, Mr Pendleton. You get around, I found your name in many places on the web today :)

Comment: Glad to hear I inspired you to keep poking at it.  Sometimes you just have to be persistent (pardon the double entendre) Stale cache bugs are a classically-frustrating category of mysterious behavior, so I'm glad you recorded the answer for others to learn from in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of Shared Cache Mode in `persistence.xml` from `Unspecified` to `None` resolves the problem I was having.